# OS X external disk eXfat disappear

Tags: macos, partitioning, external-hard-drive, gparted, exfat

I have a problem with the external drive formatted in exFAT.
When using the os x sierra drive is self unmounted and disappeared partition eXfat.
After reconnecting I had the message "disk can not be initialized"
I connected to the Windows 10 and got the message "disc is unreadable" press *something *something "MBR or GPT" and chosing MBR.
Still not have a partition exFAT.
Can I now repair disk to the previous partition exFAT?
I downloaded Geparted Live Cd and 48 hours trying to search the disk for the partition exFAT. Better gparted live cd or TestDisk?
HELP :)

Comment: Do you have any data you’re trying to recover? Or are you okay with erasing/reformatting the drive to get it working again?

Comment: ofcourse I want to recover data :) I want undelete partition!

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate from askdifferent?

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226623/repair-an-exfat-drive-on-mac-os-x-after-its-been-improperly-disconnected

Not sure how to link issues between different SO sites.